label inside a newcommand doesn't work
I am defining a \newcommand to shorten a notation I use frequently. To comment reasonings during computations I put daggers over the equal sign where such reasoning is done and hyperref it to a footnote where I articulate the reasoning. The \pug command oversets \dagger on the equal sign and hyperrefs it to the corresponding footnote. This is turn is written by \rpug, which creates the label for hyperref, writes the dagger and contains the text of the footnote.
The code is:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% To properly align equations in align environment when I use the dagger overset
\usepackage{aligned-overset}

% To remove numbering of footnotes
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}


% Clickable dagger over equal sign that redirects to correspondent footnote
\newcommand{\pug}[1]{\overset{(\hyperref[{#1}]{\dagger})}{=}}

% Corresponding footnote
\newcommand{\rpug}[2]{\label{{#1}}\footnotetext{($ \dagger $) {#2}}}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{align*}
        X \lrcorner (d\omega) &= \frac{1}{2} X^{j} \partial \ldots \\
        &\pug{foo} X^{j} (\partial \omega) \ldots
    \end{align*}
    \rpug{foo}{Since: blabla}

\end{document}

The problem consists in label not working inside such command. There is no error output but the dagger in the equation is not clickable, doesn't redirect you to the footnote and doesn't have the red color of links:

If instead I put the \label command before the \footnotetext command as (and hence not using \rpug):
\begin{align*}
    X \lrcorner (d\omega) &= \frac{1}{2} X^{j} \partial \ldots \\
    &\pug{asd} X^{j} (\partial \omega) \ldots
\end{align*}
\label{asd}\footnotetext{($ \dagger $) Since: blabla}

I get the desired result, where the hyperref works properly:

Why is this happening? How can I solve this? Thanks.

Off-topic: Unless you know there's specific reason to do otherwise, load hyperref last but one and cleveref last of all to avoid problems.

@cfr good to know, thanks

You braced label argument twice \label{{#1}}. Making it \label{#1} solves the problem
\newcommand{\rpug}[2]{\label{#1}\footnotetext{($ \dagger $) {#2}}}

